# Access Multiple table concurrently Mysql Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, concurrency

I am trying to assing a structured array from two tables, First table select query from which the value in result fetch the ID and assing to the next query, Here is my code

```
var query = db.query('select * from orderdish'),
users = [];
query
.on('error', function(err) 
{
    console.log(err);
    updateSockets(err);
})
.on('result', function(order,callback) 
{
    order.abc ='11';
    order.OrderKOT=[];

    var queryOrderKOT = db.query('select * from tblorderkot where order_Id='+ order.order_Id,function()
    {

        kotOrders = [];

        queryOrderKOT
        .on('error',function(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            updateSocket(err);
        })
        .on('result',function(orderKOT)
        {
            kotOrders.push(orderKOT);
        })     
        .on('end', function() 
        {
            console.log(kotOrders);
            order.OrderKOT.push(kotOrders);
        });
    });

    console.log(order);
    users.push(order);
    /* aa(function(){
    });*/
})
.on('end', function() 
{
    // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
    if (connectionsArray.length) 
    {
        pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
        console.log("This is End Values");
        updateSockets({ users: users });
    }
});
```

It's setting `order.OrderKOT` to empty. I know the it got to be done with call back in `query.on(result)` but if I set it's not fetching me any result. Second Query `queryOrderKOT` is working but it's fetching value pretty late and it's not pusing value to `order.OrderKOT`. Suggesst me for fetching the value concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of head breaking finally found the solution for concurrent mysql nodejs check @kevin Reilly thanks for trying a lot. I found out what ever we tried was [streaming query](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows). Which will be do the process async. Now coming back to the callback I wrote following and it's working perfectly

```
  var query = db.query('select * from orderdish', function (err, results, fields, callback) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
            updateSockets(err);
        }
        else {
            // length of results
            var count = 0;
            // pass the db object also if you wanna use the same instance
            q2(count, results, callback);
        }
    });


function q2(count, results, callbacks) {
    var queryOrderKOT = db.query('select * from tblorderkot where order_Id=' + results[count].order_Id, function (err, resultKOT, KOTFields, callback) {
        console.log(resultKOT);
        results[count].OrderKOT = resultKOT;
        count++;
        if (count < results.length) {
            q2(count, results, callback);
        }
        else {
            // do something that you need to do after this
            console.log(results);

            //callbacks(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the "end" event for the first `query` is occurring before the second `queryOrderKot` query has had a chance to complete.

You should experience the expected behavior if you move the main response logic from the "end" of `query` to the "end" or "result" of `queryOrderKot`.

Comment: I tried to do the same moved the `query.on('end', function(){` to `queryOrderKOT.on('end', function()` but `query.on('end'` is not triggering at all.

Comment: What is the client? Moving it into `result` should work

Comment: Its mysql, and still moving after result also it's still not triggering. I tried multiple combination in-fact.

Comment: What specific MySQL node.js client? I just wanted to check out the readme. Can you update your code or make a new answer with what you feel should work based on this recommendation please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my whole Code,

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'vsk',
    database: 'hahaha'
})

var POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000, connectionsArray = [], pollingTimer;
db.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
})

var socketCount = 0, restID = 0;

var pollingLoop = function () {
    var query = db.query('select * from orderdish'), users = [];
.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        updateSockets(err);
    }).on('result', function (order) {
        console.log("THis is USerID" + order.order_Id);
        order.abc = '11';
        order.OrderKOT = [];

        var queryOrderKOT = db.query('select * from tblorderkot where order_Id=' + order.order_Id);

        kotOrders = [];
        queryOrderKOT.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            updateSocket(err);
        }).on('result', function (orderKOT) {
            kotOrders.push(orderKOT);
            query.on('end', function () {
                console.log("This is at end values");
                // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
                if (connectionsArray.length) {
                    pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
                    console.log("This is End Values");
                    updateSockets({
                        users: users
                    });
                }
            });
        }).on('end', function () {
            console.log(kotOrders);
            console.log("This is my KOT End");
            order.OrderKOT.push(kotOrders);
            users.push(order);
            console.log(users);
            //callback(kotOrders);
        });
        console.log(order);
    });
};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("New Connection Opened");
    socket.on('restID', function (restIDs) {
        console.log(restIDs);
        restID = restIDs;

        console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
        if (connectionsArray.length > 0) {
            console.log("Here is the Pooling Loop");
            pollingLoop();
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
        console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
        if (socketIndex >= 0) {
            connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        }


    });

    connectionsArray.push(socket);
});
var updateSockets = function (data) { // adding the time of the last update data.time = new Date(); 
    // sending new data to all the sockets connected connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    // tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data); console.log(data); tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data); }); };
```

Comment: The content of the "end" event for the `queryOrderKOT` query probably needs to be moved to the top of the "result" event for that query. That is where the actual updating is happening, so it probably needs to happen before you send the response.

Comment: It can't be done since `order.order_Id` which is nested frest from query. Nested is where I am facing this problem. If you suggest me some other way also it would be really helpful.

Comment: The order object should be inherited by all the inner functions of the first query.